# Capturing An Image From A WebView And The Saved Image Is Always In Portrait Mode

Tags: android, webview, android-camera-intent

I am currently able to capture a image and upload it to the file-chooser. However the image is always in landscape mode regardless of how the orientation of the device. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The following is an abbreviated example of what I am currently doing.

In activityResult:

```
switch (requestCode) {
        case FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE:
            if(mUploadMessage==null)
                return;

            Uri uri=null;
                try{
                    if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)
                        uri=(data==null) ? mCapturedImageURI : data.getData();
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "activity :"+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(uri);
            mUploadMessage=null;
            break;
```

I am also implementing a WebChromeClient. Here is the relavant part of that code:

```
// openFileChooser for Android 3.0+
                public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType){
                    mUploadMessage=uploadMsg;
                        try{
                            Intent cameraIntent=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                            File externalDataDir=Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
                            File cameraDataDir=new File(externalDataDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "browser-photos");
                            cameraDataDir.mkdirs();
                            String mCameraFilePath=cameraDataDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
                            mCapturedImageURI=Uri.fromFile(new File(mCameraFilePath));

                            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,mCapturedImageURI);

                            Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                            i.setType("image/*");

                            Intent chooserIntent=Intent.createChooser(i, "Image Chooser");
                            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Parcelable[]{cameraIntent});

                            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
                        }
                        catch(Exception e){
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Camera Exception:"+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                }

                // For Android < 3.0
                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg ){
                    openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
                }

                // For Android  > 4.1.1
                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture){
                    openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType);
                }

                public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm){
                    onConsoleMessage(cm.message(), cm.lineNumber(), cm.sourceId());
                    return true;
                }

                public void onConsoleMessage(String message, int lineNumber, String sourceID){
                    Log.d("androidruntime", "www.example.com: " + message);
                }
            });     }
```

Comment: Upload an image to a file chooser? What would that be?

Comment: In a webview there is a filechooser. the code I have posted (is working) and it prompts the user to take a picture or load an image from the device. which then gets uploaded via the filechooser

Comment: Uploaded via the filechooser? Never seen such.

Comment: its just a: <input type="file">

Comment: Have you checked if file size is the same?

Comment: not sure what you mean